# ClassPath resource not found

Tags: spring-boot, cloudcontrol

I'm trying to deploy my Spring Boot based application to a CloudControl container.
I've added the `mysql.free` add-on and configured it through my `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.max-active=1
spring.datasource.max-idle=1
spring.datasource.min-idle=1
spring.datasource.initial-size=1

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQLS_HOSTNAME}:${MYSQLS_PORT}/${MYSQLS_DATABASE}
spring.datasource.username=${MYSQLS_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${MYSQLS_PASSWORD}
```

On my local development system, everything works perfectly fine, but on the CloudControl container, the app won't start.

I added the StackTrace [here](https://gist.github.com/mhmpl/82982452e86bb599e296). I'm trying to solve the problem for days, but I am not able to solve it by my own.

Comment: Are you sure that the environmental variables like `MYSQLS_HOSTNAME` are set in the production environment?

Comment: Yes definitely, I just tried it again, and it is set...

Comment: I propose you use the DEBUG log level to help you out with what's going on

Comment: Can you add more details like, how spring configuration file is setup? how properties file is referenced? where application.properties is exactly located? etc. It will help to point exact error.

Comment: My `application.properties` file looks exactly like above. It is placed in `resources/config`. I don't think that the problem is based in my config file, because when I output for example the value of `spring.datasource.url` the connection string is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring apps are very memory consuming and the `mysqls.free` addon allows only a limited number of parallel connections. Although your Stacktrace doesn't show any of these problems. It's hard to solve this issue without more context like logs or environment settings.
The following commands may help:

```
cctrlapp app_name/default log error   # shows startup log
cctrlapp app_name/default addon.creds # shows DB credentials
```

I've uploaded some spring-boot example code at https://github.com/cloudControl/spring-boot-example-app which I've tested on cloudControl today. 
Please take a look at the configuration there. If you want to deploy it, make sure your container has memory size >= 768mb.

```
cctrlapp app_name/default deploy --memory 768MB
```

If you still have issues, please contact cloudControl support to help you.